# ASP.NET Core 6 & JsonResult

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an application which searches for recording and play it. The application is running on .NET 6.0. I can display recording list in table and has play button as well.

Now I need to play recording & get text of that recording in same view/page when user click on play button in list. Below is my method which returns recording text. I need to stream text if recording size large. I can get recording text but not sure how it will display to page/view. My view model does not have this recording text field.

How can I achieve this?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetRrcording(string recKey)
{
        GetRecordingPath obj = new GetRecordingPath();
        string Path = obj.GetPath(recKey);

        SpeechRecognisation s = new SpeechRecognisation();
        string recData = s.GetData(Path);

        RecordingText rec = new RecordingText();           
        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rec);          

        return Ok(jsonString);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a suggestion like below:

You can create a new model to have this recording text field, and in the view use a `<span>` and ajax  to show the value.
For example:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult AjaxMethod(string name)
        {
          NewModel model = new NewModel
          {
              RecordingText = name,
               
            };
            return Json(model);
        }
```

View:

```
<input type="text" id="txtName" />
<input type="button" id="btnGet" value="submit" />
<sapn id="responseText"></sapn>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnGet").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Json/AjaxMethod",
                data: { "name": $("#txtName").val() },
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#responseText").html(response.recordingText);
                }
                
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Or**

Not create a new model, just return jsonString

```
return Json(jsonString);
```

And in the view:

```
 $("#responseText").html(response);
```

result:
[image]